# Avoid controls with same ID

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating dynamically controls, assigning it at the same dynamically names and ID's but when I click over a button "A" and then over the button "B" and then again to the button "A" this throw me an error

> Multiple controls with the same ID were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.

this is my code and how I try to avoid the repeating I

```
protected void DynamicButton() 
{

    //BAD TOOLS INTO THE LIST AND SHOW
    List.ListUsers listsArea = new List.ListUsers();
    List<Data.Area> Area = listsArea.AreaList();

    List<Data.Area> ListOfEquiposNoOk = Area.Where(x => x.AREA == "ENG" && x.STANDBY == 1).ToList();

    List<Button> BotonesBad = new List<Button>();

    var TeamBad = ListOfEquiposNoOk.Select(x => x.TEAM).Distinct().ToList();
    foreach (var team in TeamBad)
    {
        Button newButtonBad = new Button();
        if (newButtonBad.ID != newButtonBad.ID)
        {
            BotonesBad = Bad.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList();
            BotonesBad.Add(newButtonBad);
        }
        else
        {
            newButtonBad.CommandName = "Btn" + Convert.ToString(team);
            newButtonBad.ID = "BtnB_" + Convert.ToString(team);
            newButtonBad.Text = team;
            newButtonBad.CommandArgument = "ENG";
            newButtonBad.Click += new EventHandler(newButton_Click);

            Bad.Controls.Add(newButtonBad);
            newButtonBad.Click += new EventHandler(newButton_Click);

            newButtonBad.CssClass = "btn-primary outline separate";
        }
    }
```

I need the ID's to fire an `UpdatePanel`

**ADDED**

```
public partial class Dashboard : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        static bool enableGood = false;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                DynamicButton();
            }
            else if(enableGood)
            {
                DynamicButton();
            }
        }

        protected void DButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showAndHide();", true);

            enableGood = true;
            DynamicButton();
        }
```

Comment: this: `if (newButtonBad.ID != newButtonBad.ID)` is really stupid. It will never go in that if. Its like: `if(1 != 1)`

Comment: Could you check if the buttons are being created twice? As you are using ajax, maybe you're getting the same buttons many times

Comment: @EpicKip Your comment is correct but stupid, he has made a mistake and it's enough to point that out and nothing else

Comment: @EpicKip it's easy to overlook typos.  I can't tell you how many times I've had to ask a nearby developer to look at my code to uncover a typo i glossed over for 10 minutes.  Lighten up.

Comment: @Amy This is different. There are a ton of people just asking stackoverflow without doing any work. Many people really need a rubber duck. I mean the id is assigned with some string... and theres no checks.

Comment: @EpicKip Well, I know my code is wrong, and I'm sorry to be new in the programming world, I made many types of code trying to solve this problem, so, because I can not solve that's why I ask someone who knows more than hopeful that person can help me and not only make a bad review

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos People can't even recreate this code (as it uses data you make) so how do you expect anyone to solve it? Maybe make a test project with the same problem first, this way you usually even fix the error. And you can call it a `bad review` but I'm just being honest, you assign `"BtnB_" + Convert.ToString(team)` to each new id so obviously `team` isn't unique

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos - `newButtonBad.ID = "BtnB_" + Convert.ToString(team);` - is it possible that here `team` has spaces in its value? Maybe you have several teams with the same starting word.

Comment: @EpicKip team isn't unique, these repeats a lot of time because I assign many thigs to this, so that's why I use `var TeamBad = ListOfEquiposNoOk.Select(x => x.TEAM).Distinct().ToList();` for one reason the bucle make it twice

Comment: @DanDumitru nope, the id's create correctly but I don't know why the bucle makes twice

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos It says duplicate Id's and you KNOW its assigning duplicates... And if you `.Distinct()` it but you still get duplicate id's you might want to try actually debugging to see if the method is called twice

Comment: @EpicKip I know that is assigning duplicates, but I don't know why, I repeat, I make some break point and I can see that when I clic by first time the foreach run normally, but when I make a second click over the same button, run the loop, but when this finish, start again, so that's why duplicate the ID's

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos So.. do you want to generate a set of controls from the same data twice? if not and they should be different you could give an index as parameter and add that to id. then increment on each call. `but when I make a second click over the same button, run the loop, but when this finish, start again, so that's why duplicate the ID's` < What do you mean exactly, does it restart the loop? Does it go without you clicking?

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos - Can you show us the code where you call this `DynamicButton` method from?

Comment: @DanDumitru yes, let me add

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos - So, it seems you are calling the `DynamicButton` method several times: on the first page load, in `if (!IsPostBack)`; then, when the `DButton` event gets fired; after that, on every postback, in `else if(enableGood)`. Why aren't you calling it only once?

Comment: @DanDumitru oh it was that, I delete the `else if` from the `Page_Load`

Comment: @DanDumitru that fix the error but makes another jeje, if I delete that part of code the event doesn't fire

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "team" is an object in this line:

```
newButtonBad.ID = "BtnB_" + Convert.ToString(team);
```

There could be your problem. ".ToString()" usually returns the type as string. So every button will get the same name (since they are all of type "team").

You could override ToString() in your team object, or use a specific team property (e.g team.ID). You could use the property like this:

```
newButtonBad.ID = "BtnB_" + team.ID.ToString();
```

Also as already pointed out in the comments, change your evaluation from

```
if (newButtonBad.ID != newButtonBad.ID)
```

to

```
if (team.ID != newButtonBad.ID)
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: The line `newButtonBad.Text = team;` suggests that `team` is a `string`.

Comment: Button ids are `BtnB_" ` + team id so the last if won't work

Comment: True, but why Convert.ToString(team) if it's already as string? If team **is** a `string`, the problem could be teams have a identical names? I also noticed the Click handler is added twice.